# What could cause async lambda to return unwanted data about the operation in Ok IActionResult?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I tried to use await in my lambda function to have an operation done asynchronously, to simplify the question I left out unnecessary operations (where clauses etc) and I named the async method `Services.CustomerAmountService.QueryDbAndReturnResult`

The function takes a double (sum of amount) and does numerous tasks, but most importantly an async call (firstAsync, which makes the function awaitable)

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomersAndAmount()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok((await _orderRepository.CustomMadeQueryThatReturnsIQueryable()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
                CustomerName = x.Customer.Name
                Amount = x.Amount
            })
            .ToListAsync())
            .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId )
            // this "async x" causes the unwanted result in my Ok() IActionResult
            .Select( async x => new
            {
                CustomerName = x.First().CustomerName,
                SumAmount = await Services.CustomerAmountService.QueryDbAndReturnResult(x.Sum(x => x.Amount)) 
            })
        ));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"1":[{"result":{"customerName":"VeryNiceCustomer","amount":1.0},"id":1269,"exception":null,"status":5,"isCanceled":false,"isCompleted":true,"isCompletedSuccessfully":true,"creationOptions":0,"asyncState":null,"isFaulted":false}]}
```

But the desired result and the result without "async x" and an async function (so just returning '1' and doing no further operations at all) looks like this:

```
{"1":[{"customerName":"VeryNiceCustomer","amount":1}]}
```

Im wondering what I can change to always get the second result, and not worry about returning unnecessary data about the operation ? It seems to be returing a Result, but I'm only interested in the Result of the Result (what the function returns, not the async Result)

Answer (score 1):

`async` lambda is transformed into [`Func<T, Task<T>>`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI4DcyamcArOSgMyYzoDC6A3sut5o1ACzoAsgAoAlBy490ANwCGAJ3QAPdAF50hAKYB3ANoBdDujjoAvlOk9sAZS0AbLQGMALiKgAOFeoB8mAJyYAGzYAGIKAPYAtgBKWgDOAK72bnBiYnTSFkhmQA=) so your return is actually of type `IEnumerable<Task<GeneratedAnonymousType>>`. You can use `Task.WhenAll` to transform the results:

```cs
var resultTasks = (await _orderRepository.CustomMadeQueryThatReturnsIQueryable()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = x.Customer.Name
        Amount = x.Amount
    })
    .ToListAsync())
    .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId )
    .Select( async x => new
    {
        CustomerName = x.First().CustomerName,
        SumAmount = await Services.CustomerAmountService.QueryDbAndReturnResult(x.Sum(x => x.Amount)) 
    }));

return Ok(await Task.WhenAll(resultTasks));
```

But in general I would recommend to revise tha whole approach - usually having parallel processing in action is a smell. Writing a method wich will fetch all needed data in one query should be better.

Comment: I would never suggest using `WhenAll` with Entity Framework.

Comment: Dear Guru, I understand your solution to the problem, but the issue is that the return type is still not  "IEnumerable<Task<GeneratedAnonymousType>>" and thus the " Task.WhenAll(resultTasks)" greets me with an error :(

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, do you have an alternative? :-)

Comment: @PurpleTurtle what is the actuall error text?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv not sure that `Services.CustomerAmountService.QueryDbAndReturnResult` uses EF.

Comment: Me too. But name is suspicious ;) And if OP uses scoped DbContext, everything will fail.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, it is. Though it is quite strange (for me) descision to mix repositories and services on the same level (especially in the controller). The reason why I suggested this - cause it already does not fail =)

Comment: @GuruStron Do you have any references on how to seperate my logic properly? :-) Stil learning every day

Comment: @PurpleTurtle personally I see no point in repositories which return `IQueryable`'s. So I either use context directly where needed, cause it already implements Repository/UoW patterns or create repositories which returns evealuated query results (usually mapped into some DTO's, not using entites).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use async in LINQ methods. You have to enumerate results by foreach and make `await` calls.
Schematically:

```
foreach (var x in items)
   SumAmount = await Services.CustomerAmountService.QueryDbAndReturnResult(x.Sum(x => x.Amount))
```

But, I think, your query just not optimal:

```cs
var query = _orderRepository.CustomMadeQueryThatReturnsIQueryable()
   .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = x.Customer.Name
    })
   .Select(g => new 
    {
         CustomerName = g.Key.CustomerName,
         SumAmount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    });

return return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
```